# Getting apt warnings when updating Ubuntu

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, ppa, repository

I'm getting this error when running sudo apt update. I'm sure it's something simple and have tried to check my sources.list and sources.list.d but can't seem to make heads or tails of it. Thanks!

```
463 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gencfsm/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/i18n/Translation-en_US' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu bionic InRelease' doesn't have the component 'main' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Comment: When you added your PPAs, you made a typo. Each time. PPAs's don't have a 'main'. Remove that word from your PPA sources.

Comment: I must have. I just removed the offending ppas are re-added them and the warnings went away.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up removing the genfcsm and git-core ppas entirely and just re-added them back. That solved the warnings problem.